# How to run task after the blocking action like webpack:watch in NPM

Tags: npm, webpack

I am using webpack:watch to compile and watch all css and js, and then I would like to restart express server. However, it seems like the thread is blocked by webpack:watch, so it wont execute subsequent script to start express

Here is the code

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack:watch express:restart",
    "express:restart" : "....."
  },
```

I am using node 6. I wonder is there any npm script I can use to achieve that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try going through webpack Node API? I know it's more code to write but at least then you should have more control over the behavior. You could also try something like `npm run webpack:watch && npm run express:start` if you want to go through Unix.